# How to I correct in my php files to get rid of the "PHP version not specified" error?

Tags: php

I'm working on cleaning up my code.  In ESLint in Visual Code, I am getting this error at the heading of my code and I can't figure out how to correct it. What is the syntax to correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got 2 or more versions of PHP installed. Remove one and should work

Comment: I have more than 1 PHP version installed myself and have never seen this error message before.

Comment: Then try uninstalling older versions until the error disappears

Comment: I don't have that error.  I'm just pointing out that when installed correctly you can have many versions of PHP installed.  I still have clients that use older version so I want that version available.